# IE Mobile evaluating screen dimensions before user confirm

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, ie-mobile

I only want to go fullscreen if the device is in landscape. Here's my code:

```
if(window.innerHeight>window.innerWidth){
    if(confirm('Go landscape then tap "ok".')){
        alert(window.innerHeight<window.innerWidth);
    }else{
        alert('You hit cancel.');
    }
}else{
    alert('Device is already in landscape.');
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8w36z3rL/ (Short link of result; no need to type the whole thing on your phone: http://goo.gl/KRWZOu)

My problem is that `alert(window.innerHeight<window.innerWidth);` always displays `false`. Even if I rotate and wait several seconds before hitting "OK".

How can I get around this?